# Django template addition inside {% with %} is not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm populating table with forloop in django template

```
<tbody>
              {% with total=0 %}
              {% for inv in row.investmentdetails_set.all %}
              <tr>
                <th>{{ inv.investment_type }}</th>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.enterprise }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.investment }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.investment_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.maturity_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.monthly_returns }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.maturity_status }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% with total=total|add:inv.monthly_returns %}{% endwith %}
              {% endfor %}
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7">{{total}}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endwith %}
            </tbody>
```

total always printed 0

i tried {{ total }} between inner with it printed "2000" everytime
instead of printing 2000 4000 6000

I'm populating table with forloop in django template

```
<tbody>
              {% with total=0 %}
              {% for inv in row.investmentdetails_set.all %}
              <tr>
                <th>{{ inv.investment_type }}</th>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.enterprise }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.investment }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.investment_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.maturity_date|date:'Y-m-d' }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.monthly_returns }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ inv.maturity_status }}</td>
              </tr>
              {% with total=total|add:inv.monthly_returns %}{% endwith %}
              {% endfor %}
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7">{{total}}</td>
              </tr>
              {% endwith %}
            </tbody>
```

total always printed 0

i tried {{ total }} between inner with it printed "2000" everytime
instead of printing 2000 4000 6000

Comment: The `with` template tag creates a new "scope" so to speak so when you're writing `{% with total=total|add:inv.monthly_returns %}` it creates a new scope with that value being the `total` in the next iteration that scope is obviously gone so your loops starts from 0 again. You can create some custom template tag or you can simply move that logic to your views. A good choice would be to use a [Window expression as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227749/django-cumulative-sum-or-running-sum)

Comment: Do not calculate in templates. Business logic belongs in the view.

Answer (score 0):

A simple cli example for better understanding (multi lines):

```
>>> from jinja2.nativetypes import NativeEnvironment
>>> env = NativeEnvironment()
>>> t = env.from_string(
...     '{% for i in range(5) %}'
...         '{{ total+i }}'
...     '{% endfor %}'
...     '{{ "**" + total|string }}'
... )
>>> t.render(total=0)
```

Output:

```
'01234**0'
```

Same example with **with** ^^

```
>>> t = env.from_string('{% for i in range(5) %}{% with total=total+i %}{% endwith %}{% endfor %}{{ "**" + total|string }}')
>>> t.render(total=0)
```

Output:

```
'**0'
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#with

> only available between the {% with %} and {% endwith %} tags

*total* will never be updated outside tags.
As mentionned in comments, you'll have to deal with it in views.